# virtualenv does not include pip

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to create a virtual environment using `virtualenv` on Mac OS X El Capitan. I have installed Python 2.7.11 with `brew`, which includes `pip`,  `wheel` and `setuptools` by default.

Hovewer, when I try to install `virtualenv` following instructions in the [documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html) or from any other resource, I get several problems:

1. `virtualenv` executable is not placed in `/usr/local/bin` after `pip` makes its job, so I need to `ln -s` it by hand (it may indicate, that there is something wrong with installation on this step).
2. After I run `virtualenv venv`, it creates new environment, catches Python 2.7.11 from `brew`-installation, but: *there is no `pip` inside `bin` folder*. That means, that if I try `which pip`, having `venv` activated, it returns a global position of `pip` — `/usr/local/bin/pip`, not `/path/to/venv/bin/pip`.

As a consequence, installing packages inside `venv` uses global `pip` and installs them to a global `sites-packages`, not that inside `venv`, and it's quite the opposite of what environment should do.

Could you please suggest what may be wrong and how to fix it?

EDIT: The thing to mention is that I used to have other versions of Python installed on my computer, which I have recently deleted as it is described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3819449/3885799). Maybe it causes the issue, and some more thorough cleaning is needed.

Comment: Did you use `sudo` when installing `virtualenv`? Maybe it got installed as a user-private package somehow and that's causing the troubles. (Like not having wherever binaries are placed during that installation on `PATH` etc.)

Comment: @millimoose I tried both without `sudo` and with it, the result is the same. It is unlikely the problem of privileges, as it is possible to use `virtualenv.py` [locally from source](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html). Using `virtualenv.py` from tarball also strangely fails to ship `pip`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try removing or renaming the .pydistutils.cfg file in your home directory, e.g. by renaming with `mv ~/.pydistutils.cfg ~/oldpydistutils.cfg`

I'm putting a detailed answer here to help others, but the original credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38908532/4619397). If you know what specifically in .pydistutils.cfg was causing the problem, let me know!

I was having the same issue: my virtual environments were created without a local copy of pip, although they had a local copy of python. This meant that using `$ pip` from within the virtual environment installed to the global package location, and was not visible to the environment's python.

How I diagnosed this on my machine:

1. I create a virtualenvironment with `$ virtualenv env`
2. Activated the virtual environment with `$ source env/bin/activate`
3. Checked python location: run `(env)$ which python` with output `/Users/<username>/env/bin/python` (as expected)
4. Checked pip location: run `(env)$ which pip` with output `/usr/local/bin/pip` (NOT expected)

To check where our packages are going, we can try to install a package in the virtual environment:

5. Try to install a package: `(env)$ pip install HTTPServer` which succeeds
6. Try to run the package: `(env)$ python -m HTTPServer` which fails with error `/Users/emunsing/env/bin/python: No module named HTTPServer`
7. To double-check, try to install again: `(env)$ pip install HTTPServer` which produces `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): HTTPServer in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Double-checking, we see that there's no Pip in the environment's /bin folder:

`$ ls env/bin
activate        activate.fish       python          python2
activate.csh    activate_this.py    python-config   python2.7`

And so while the system finds the local python version, it can't find a local pip to use and traverses the $PATH. It ended up using pip from /usr/local/bin, leaving me unable to install packages locally to the virtual environment.

Here's what I tried:
- Reinstalling python `brew uninstall python` followed by `brew upgrade` and `brew install python --build-from-source`
- Installing pip [using the get-pip.py command as described in the Pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

Here's what I ruled out:
- I was not using `sudo pip ...` [which caused similar problems in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695278/python-packages-not-installing-in-virtualenv-using-pip) and haven't done so at any time on this Python/pip install
- My virtual environment didn't show a local installation of pip, as was the case in these similar questions: [This one for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709120/pip-not-installing-to-site-packages-directory-from-within-virtualenv-when-i-use), [This one for Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952797/pip-installing-in-global-site-packages-instead-of-virtualenv?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Ultimately, I found that eliminating the `~/.pydistutils.cfg` file fixed the problem, allowing for fresh virtual environments that had their own local pip. The contents of my `~/.pydistutils.cfg` file were:

```
[global]
verbose=1

[install]
install-scripts=$HOME/bin

[easy_install]
install-scripts=$HOME/bin
```

Simply renaming the `~/.pydistutils.cfg` file appears to fix the problem: it seems that although this file was created by the homebrew installation, [some settings in this file may be incompatible with virtualenv](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/769). While removing this file hasn't had any bad effects on my system, you may need to use the `--user` flag when installing packages with pip to the global environment (e.g. `$ pip install --user HTTPServer`). Here are more [details on .pydistutils.cfg](http://bouktin.blogspot.com/2012/04/configure-pydistutilscfg-python.html) if you want to work on tailoring it for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I just wanted to say that cannot confirm the answer, as I do not longer experience the mentioned issue. I have a new computer and, thankfully, cannot reproduce that. However, if someone can confirm that this solution works, I will happily approve your answer.

Comment: This is absolutely correct. I removed the file ~/.pydistutils.cfg and all my problems were solved. Thank you for summarizing a lot of information in one answer.

Comment: I cannot find the file `.pydistutils.cfg`, used `locate .pydistutils.cfg` but couldn't find it, same error and debugging shows the same problems. Any other solution. System: Ubuntu

Comment: @Vaulstein : This question and answer were specific to Mac OS X, probably because .pydistutils.cfg is edited by homebrew (for Mac). I'm not able to replicate the problem on the Ubuntu systems I have access to, but if you find a solution definitely post a comment, or if you don't find a solution then maybe post a Linux-specific question and link to this!

Comment: @emunsing, it seems like i am getting same problem of not able to install with pip inside venv. But I am not getting your #4 step. When I do 'which pip' it gives me my environment's path. Also I am not getting any .pydistutils.cfg file in my home directory. Is there any other cause generating this problem on my machine? Please help.

Comment: @MrSingh It sounds like you have a different question- and to diagnose it, you'll need to provide details on what happens when you attempt to `pip install` a package. As this stackoverflow question is specific to 'virtualenv does not include pip' you may want to create a new question if you're not able to find a solution, so that others with the same problem can also be helped.

Comment: Hi @emunsing, I actually got the solution by hitting my head and doing hit and trial. So what happens is that if I create virtual environment folder 'my-python-env' in my home directory directly then it's fine otherwise if I go one level deeper by creating a folder first (ex: 'envs') in home directory and then create virtual environment folder 'my-python-env' inside it, pip does not work. 
Anyways thanks. :)

Comment: `which -a pip` would output what you are expecting

Answer (score 4):

> 1. `virtualenv` executable is not placed in `/usr/local/bin` after `pip` makes its job, so I need to `ln -s` it by hand (it may indicate, that there is something wrong with installation on this step).

Don't do that. That will only hide the bug and not solve the problem. Here's a short guide how to debug this kind of issues:

- Start with `which -a python`. The first path you see should be `/usr/local/bin/python`, if not check your `PATH` variable.
- Next, check `which -a pip`. Again the first path should be `/usr/local/bin/pip`. If not, run `python -m ensurepip` and recheck.
- Now install `virtualenv` using `pip install virtualenv`, after that check the output of `which -a virtualenv`. The first path should be `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`, if not check the output of `env |grep PYTHON` for unexpected environment variables.
- Finally check the output of `virtualenv --version` to make sure you have the latest version.

Comment: Double-checked everything you said. Everything points to `/usr/local/bin/…` first, as well as `virtualenv`, which is at version 13.1.2. `env` shows nothing related to `PYTHON`, although it indeed looks like environment variables problem. Anywhere else to look?

Comment: did you remove the symlink you created before? Can you reinstall `virtualenv` and add the output you get from `pip`, also the output from `virtualenv` when you create a new venv. Also can you print the commands you use to activate the `venv` and `echo $PATH` after activating the venv.

Comment: Symlink is created properly only when I use `--isolated` option, it makes `pip` to correctly generate `virtualenv` in `/usr/local/bin`. Using this `virtualenv` still does not give `pip` in created `venv`. Here is the output: http://pastebin.com/BbG8Ytap

Comment: I have a similar problem; virtualenv is not installing to /usr/local/bin but instead to /Users/username/bin (OS X El Capitan, python 2.7, pip 7.1.2). The output of `env |grep PYTHON` is empty... any ideas; @cel?

Comment: @emunsing, what is the output of `which -a pip`?

Comment: @cel the output I get is `/usr/local/bin/pip  \n  /Users/emunsing/bin/pip`

Answer (score 2):

I had the issue when running virtualenv: "ImportError: No module named pip."
My solution was to downgrade virtualenv.  I had 16.2.0.
pip uninstall virtualenv
pip install virtualenv==15.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Just hit same issue on Linux. Seems like there are multiple causes of this issue, but for me answer was to remove `~/.pip/`.

Details: I had this in my `.pip/pip.conf` for some reason I can't remember:

```
$ cat ~/.pip/pip.conf 
[global]
use_https = True 
index = https://pypi.python.org/pypi
prefix = /home/sam/local/
```

and was using local versions on Python, Pip installed at ~/local/. For some reason `virtualenv` installed pip must pick up `prefix = /home/sam/local/` setting and pip was being installed there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `sudo apt install pythonV.v-distutils`.
In my case V.v == 3.8.
This worked for me.