# pip missing from Python venv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-3.5

When I create a new virtualenv using `python3.5`, it creates the virtualenv using `Python 3.5.2` as expected, but is missing `pip`:

```
jpmelos@jpmelos-laptop:~$ pi<TAB COMPLETION>
pi1toppm         pilconvert       pinentry         ping6
pi3topbm         pildriver        pinentry-curses  pinky
pic              pilfile          pinentry-gnome3  pip3.6
piconv           pilfont          pinentry-x11     pivot_root
pidof            pilprint         ping             pixeltool
jpmelos@jpmelos-laptop:~$ python3.5 -m venv myvenv
jpmelos@jpmelos-laptop:~$ source myvenv/bin/activate
(myvenv) jpmelos@jpmelos-laptop:~$ pi<TAB COMPLETION>
pi1toppm         pilconvert       pinentry         ping6
pi3topbm         pildriver        pinentry-curses  pinky
pic              pilfile          pinentry-gnome3  pip3.6
piconv           pilfont          pinentry-x11     pivot_root
pidof            pilprint         ping             pixeltool
(myvenv) jpmelos@jpmelos-laptop:~$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Dec 28 2016, 10:08:00)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
(myvenv) jpmelos@jpmelos-laptop:~$
```

What is going on? Shouldn't there be a `pip` binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.pydistutils.cfg` file in your home directory.

```
rm ~/.pydistutils.cfg
```

This is nicely explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503686/virtualenv-does-not-include-pip).

Comment: It's not there, but I remember experimenting with this a few days ago to see how it worked, so maybe I screwed things up somehow and didn't know. I'll read your link and try to figure it out, thanks!