# Pip does not work in a virtual environment. Fish-Shell,

Tags: python, shell, arch

I use a fish shell, activate a virtual environment, Python works from the environment, but pip is used globally. How to fix it?

```
$ which python
/develop/venv/bin/python 
$ which pip
/usr/bin/pip 
$ python -m pip --version
pip 21.1 from /develop/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip
```

~ / .pydistutils.cfg The file does not exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip missing from Python venv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426275/pip-missing-from-python-venv)

Comment: Unfortunately no( ~ / .pydistutils.cfg The file does not exist.

Comment: What's with the spaces? It should be `~/.pydistutils.cfg`

Comment: ```
.
├── .bash_history
├── .bash_logout
├── .bash_profile
├── .bashrc
├── .cache
├── .config
├── .firedragon
├── .gtkrc-2.0
├── .icons
├── .java
├── .kde4
├── .lesshst
├── .local
├── .mozilla
├── pkglist.txt
├── .pki
├── .profile
├── .ssh
├── .wget-hsts
├── .whatsdesk
├── .Xauthority
├── .xinitrc
```