# Fill requirements.txt from PyCharm virtual environment

Tags: django, pip, pycharm, requirements.txt

I am trying to fill a requirements.txt for my PyCharm Django project that has a virtual environment. I am using the following when my virtual environment has been started:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This creates lots of entries as shown here but does not have entries for packages I have added such as djangorestframework, Django-crispy-forms etc.

What do I have to do to get all my packages listed? None of the packages installed within the virtual environment `venv/lib/python 3.6/site-packages` are listed in the requirements.txt

At the moment my requirements.txt looks like this:

```html
altgraph==0.10.2
amqp==2.1.4
appdirs==1.4.3
awsebcli==3.10.0
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1
bdist-mpkg==0.5.0
billiard==3.5.0.2
blessed==1.14.1
bonjour-py==0.3
botocore==1.5.26
cement==2.8.2
click==6.7
colorama==0.3.7
coreapi==2.3.0
coreschema==0.0.4
defusedxml==0.4.1
django-appconf==1.0.2
dockerpty==0.4.1
funcsigs==1.0.2
futures==3.1.1
itypes==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.9.6
jmespath==0.9.2
kombu==4.0.2
macholib==1.5.1
MarkupSafe==1.0
matplotlib==1.3.1
modulegraph==0.10.4
numpy==1.8.0rc1
oauthlib==2.0.1
olefile==0.44
openapi-codec==1.3.1
packaging==16.8
pathspec==0.5.0
pbr==3.0.1
progressbar2==3.20.0
psycopg2==2.7.3.2
py2app==0.7.3
PyJWT==1.5.0
pyobjc-core==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Accounts==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Automator==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreData==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreText==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-EventKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Message==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PubSub==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-QTKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Quartz==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Social==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-WebKit==2.5.1
pyOpenSSL==0.13.1
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==1.5
python-openid==2.2.5
pytz==2013.7
PyYAML==3.12
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
scipy==0.13.0b1
semantic-version==2.5.0
simplejson==3.10.0
six==1.10.0
social-auth-app-django==1.2.0
social-auth-core==1.3.0
sqlparse==0.2.3
tabulate==0.7.5
termcolor==1.1.0
uritemplate==3.0.0
vboxapi==1.0
vine==1.1.3
virtualenv==15.1.0
wcwidth==0.1.7
websocket-client==0.40.0
xattr==0.6.4
zope.interface==4.1.1
```

Comment: activate the virtualenv first

Comment: I have run 'source venv/bin/activate' to activate my virtual environment and run 'pip freeze' but it doesn't put the packages in the requirements.txt file. I get the same as before.

Comment: probably some if these packages are installed globally?

Comment: The packages are installed within the virtual environment venv/lib/python 3.6/site-packages. None of these packages are listed in the requirements.txt

Comment: if You are using one of *nix system could You add output from command `which pip` ?

Comment: @Take_Care_ which pip gives me: /Users/billnoble/.pyenv/shims/pip I am running on a Mac

Comment: You need to call venv/bin/pip, the pip version installed in your virt environment. Also you could try pip3

Comment: @SabirAkhadov there is no pip in vent/bin/pip

Comment: This looks like your virtual env is not properly setup. I would suggest you use `virtualenvwrapper` instead. See this link https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html and install virtualenv wrapper as per the document. Then use `mkproject <name>` to create the project. You can use the variables `WORKON_HOME` and `PROJECT_HOME` to let it load existing virtual environments

Comment: @TarunLalwani I have a working virtual environment at venv/ and am trying to get a requirements.txt for this

Comment: Are you installing the packages via PyCharm? If so, there is a checkbox for "Install to user's site packages directory". Is this checked or unchecked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Since the follow up in the comments, we have reached the conclusion that the virtual environment that @BillNoble created didn't have `pip` installed in it and that was what caused the problem.

By following this post: [virtualenv does not include pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503686/virtualenv-does-not-include-pip) he was able to solve it.

I will leave my previous answer here because it is the answer to the initial phrasing of the question.

---

**Pycharm Version 2017.2**:

1. Go to: File > Settings > Project:  > Project interpreter
2. In there, hit the button with the cog symbol.
   If you have a virtual environment, choose "add local" (**3**).
   If you don't have a virtual environment, choose "create VirtualEnv" (**4**).
3. **Add local:** Navigate to your virtual environments folder and find your existing one. Then choose: path/to/venv **/my_venv/bin/pythonX.X**
4. **Create VirtualEnv:** Just give it a name and select the python version you want.
5. Go to Pycharm terminal and activate your virtual env (or restart pycharm).

**(EDIT: added after Pycharm update) Pycharm Version 2017.3.3**:

1. Go to: File > Settings > Project:  > Project interpreter
2. In there, hit the button with the cog symbol and choose "Add Local":
   If you have a virtual environment, choose "Existing environment" (**3**).
   If you don't have a virtual environment, choose "New environment" (**4**).
3. **Existing environment:** In the "Interpreter" tab, navigate to your virtual environments folder and find your existing one. Then choose: path/to/venv **/my_venv/bin/pythonX.X**
4. **New environment:** Define the location of the virtual environment in the "Location" tab (usually `home/username/.virtualenvs/your_venv`) and choose the base interpreter from the drop-down menu.
5. Go to Pycharm terminal and activate your virtual env (or restart pycharm).

Now install anything you need and when you do a `pip freeze > requirements.txt` you will get everything installed inside your virtual env.

*Keep in mind that you don't need everything from your venv inside your `requirement.txt`. Most of the modules in there are dependencies of other modules (like Django) and the correct version of them will get installed if you try to install the depended package.*

Comment: @BillNoble Then follow step 3 without step 4

Comment: I have tried that but pip freeze is still not listing the Django packages installed in the virtual environment

Comment: @BillNoble When you call `pip freeze` without the `> requirements.txt` part, do you see the Django module?

Comment: No I just see what is listed in my question

Comment: @BillNoble Try to reinstall Django (`pip install django`) and then `pip freeze` again. Do you see it now?

Comment: If I run pip install from the command line where my virtual environment is active it is trying to install Django in the wrong place. I get this error: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django'

Comment: @BillNoble Did you create your virtual env using `sudo`? Anyway, try to create a new virtual env (preferably if you are a new user, try creating it via Pycharm) and retry your installation.

Comment: The virtual environment was created by PyCharm and activate by 'source vent/bin/activate

Comment: There is no pip in venv/bin

Comment: @BillNoble try something like this then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503686/virtualenv-does-not-include-pip

Comment: I don't have a pydistutils.cfg file so I am not sure how that helps. Is there a straightforward way to install pip in my virtual environment?

Comment: I have managed to Install pip in my virtual environment and now I get the correct contents for my requirements.txt. If you would like to update your answer to reflect this I will award the points to you.